# Mac OS HSDB HotSpot Debugger can not attach to the process

Tags: java, macos, debugging, jvm-hotspot, jdb

I want to use HSDB to debug my java code. I follow the steps blow:

1. Debug my code in IntelliJ and stop at a breakpoint
2. Start HSDB:

   > java -cp ,:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB
3. use jps to get the pid 
   [image]
4. attach to the pid, but error occurs.
   [image]
   [image]

My java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

My os version:

```
  System Version: macOS 10.13.3 (17D102)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 17.4.0
  Boot Volume: 未命名
  Boot Mode: Normal
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Time since boot: 6 days 1:08
```

Can someone gives me some advices? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I need to use sudo

> sudo java -cp ,:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB

Comment: is that working? didn't work out to me